# read index.dat file c#

Tags: c#-3.0

HI,

I want to read index.dat file of user in c#.

Comment: Is there a non-nefarious purpose for this?

Comment: You need to add **a lot** more information if you want anyone to answer your question. Things like what you tried, what the problems you are having and the errors you are having will help people understand your question and you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader objInput = new StreamReader("C:\\values.dat", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
string contents = objInput.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```